# C# Chat application freezes when code is executed

Tags: c#, chat

so I have been working on my chat application in c# as a windows form application and when this code to receive data has to be executed the program freezes.

Anyone help me please, finding out whats wrong about this. As a console application it works.

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text));

            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            textMsg.Text = returnData.ToString();
```

Comment: If you are using a debugger, can you be more specific about where it freezes?

Comment: lookup how you can use [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: at "Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);" (it seems like that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is frozen because the UdpClient class's Receive(...) method is blocking.

That is to say, it will stop at that point of execution and not allow the thread/process it is in to continue until it receives a **single** UDP packet.  This includes the UI unless you put this in a separate thread or us an asynchronous communication model.

If you want to handle communications asynchronously, [check out the BeginReceive(...) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And here is some example code (Originally, I was using this code[straight from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  However, it was missing the definition for UdpState.  After some teeth gnashing, I figured out you had to create it to pass your own state in so the asynchronous model would work as expected.  The example has been updated and compiles in VS2008, .Net 3.5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class UdpState
    {
        public IPEndPoint e = null;
        public UdpClient u = null;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static bool messageReceived = false;

        public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
            IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

            Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
            string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
            messageReceived = true;
        }

        public static void ReceiveMessages(int listenPort)
        {
            // Receive a message and write it to the console.
            IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
            UdpClient u = new UdpClient(e);

            UdpState s = new UdpState();
            s.e = e;
            s.u = u;

            Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
            u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

            // Do some work while we wait for a message. For this example,
            // we'll just sleep
            while (!messageReceived)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReceiveMessages(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Was this helpful?

Comment: yes thanks the only problem left is i dont understand how to build-in the begin recieve method into my code.

Comment: I added some example code for you.  You have to define a callback to receive the message.  This could be a method in your UI which adds the message to a list or just adds it to a text box, etc.

Comment: it doesnt work with the UdpState. it says that it couldnt be found.

Comment: You have to define UdpState as your own "data object" class that gets passed back by reference in the callback.  This is a common model (though I haven't done it for a while, so I forgot).  I updated the example, which compiles for me in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate how threading works.
In windows forms you could use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On msdn you can even find a working sample code.
PS: be sure not to call UI controls directly in the DoWork event (it runs on another thread). If you really need to, invoke it through the Invoke method that exists in every windows forms control.